# Sencha touch Chart inside Carousel or any other container

Tags: extjs, charts, touch, carousel

Hello i am trying to put CartesianChart inside Carousel but it doesn't 
render. 
So if i invoke Chart using this:

```
Ext.create('app.view.CompanyStockChart', {fullscreen: true});
```

it works well, like this:

[Example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DI31D.png)

If i use Carousel to render Chart, it doesn't work, and only show the logo of SenchaTouch:

[Example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fjyce.png)

code:

```
    var pnl5=Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'middle'
            },
        title: 'Chart',
        iconCls: 'overview',
        items:[{
        xtype: 'companystockchart'
        }],
        listeners: {
            activate: function() {
            }
        }
    })

    var crs = Ext.create('Ext.Carousel', {
        fullscreen: true,
        direction: 'horizontal',
        defaults: {
            styleHtmlContent: true
        },
        items: [
        pnl1,
        pnl5,
        pnl2,
        pnl3,
        pnl4
        ]
    });
```

code of companystockchart:

```
Ext.define('app.view.CompanyStockChart', {
   extend: 'Ext.chart.CartesianChart',
   alias: 'widget.companystockchart',

config: {
    store: 'StockDataStore',
    axes: [
        {
            type: 'time',
            fields: [
                'date'
            ]
        },
        {
            type: 'numeric',
            fields: [
                'open'
            ],
            grid: {
                odd: {
                    fill: '#e8e8e8'
                }
            },
            position: 'left'
        }
    ],
    series: [
        {
            type: 'line',
            style: {
                smooth: true,
                stroke: 'rgb(0,200,0)',
                fill: 'rgba(0,200,0,0.3)'
            },
            xField: 'date',
            yField: 'open'
        }
    ],
    interactions: [
        {
            type: 'panzoom'
        }
    ]
}

});
```

The same problem occurs when I use other type of containers instead of the carousel.
What should i do for solving this problem?
pls help me)

Answer (score 0):

Thanx to all, i've done it using layout: 'fit' in config section of pnl5

```
    var pnl5=Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        layout: 'fit',
        title: 'Chart',
```